# Failed to run any NPM Command Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1

Tags: macos, angular6, npm-install

I'm trying to uninstall node-sass using "npm uninstall node-sass", but I am not able to run any npm command as it gives the following error.

> Undefined variable standalone_static_library in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
> gyp ERR! configure error
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1

Recently, when I tried to run `ng build`, it was giving me a phython2 error. I installed python2 on my Mac M1 using:

```
pyenv install 2.7.18
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
export PATH="${HOME}/.pyenv/shims:${PATH}"
```

Comment: Can you try `npm install -g node-gyp` ?